# Two docker containers attached to same network but can't reference each other by name, only IP

Tags: docker

**I have 2 docker containers running attached to same network.  From within container 1 I can ping container 2 by *IP* (and vice versa).  But from within container 1 I can't ping container 2 by *name* (nor vice versa).**

According to this I should be able to ping by container name: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks

What am I doing wrong?

```
//START MYSQL IN CONTAINER ONE CONNECTING TO TESTNET
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -e MYSQL_DATABASE=MyDb -p 3306:3306 --network testnet -d mysql:latest
7ba710ca9ed0ffd346416eae31553460799cc1bedf3f7cfa9d7ef3b369e41f7e

//START MYEXECUTABLE IN CONTAINER TWO CONNECTING TO TESTNET
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run -p 8948:8948 --network testnet -d myexecutable:ubuntu
399c19d4adaf9cb6679ed062cf92455d1dd2d83087d51966e6a4d499dc312909

//BOTH CONTAINERS RUNNING
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
399c19d4adaf        myexecutable:ubuntu    "dotnet myexecut…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8948->8948/tcp              optimistic_lamport
7ba710ca9ed0        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   charming_gates

//INSPECT TESTNET, SEE THAT BOTH CONTAINERS CONNECTED
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker network inspect testnet
[
    {
        "Name": "testnet",
        "Id": "8db5e107100350f594d405890f94a8f0770aae37ae71a102cbbdb24baa27e117",
        "Created": "2020-03-11T11:24:45.060816989Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "399c19d4adaf9cb6679ed062cf92455d1dd2d83087d51966e6a4d499dc312909": {
                "Name": "optimistic_lamport",
                "EndpointID": "a99566e018a295f28ffc6758e3e78dfa0b1f5292dedfef0546e8ceaed11b2b3d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7ba710ca9ed0ffd346416eae31553460799cc1bedf3f7cfa9d7ef3b369e41f7e": {
                "Name": "charming_gates",
                "EndpointID": "78729185c317d096a637d637929d3bd3d32dec9f5587327bc5703ac708225d37",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]

//ATTACH TO CONTAINER ONE SHELL
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker exec -it optimistic_lamport bash

//PING CONTAINER TWO BY IP - WORKS FINE
    root@399c19d4adaf:/app# ping -c 2 172.18.0.2
    PING 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
    64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms

//PING CONTAINER TWO BY NAME - FAIL
    root@399c19d4adaf:/app# ping -c 2 charming_gates
    ping: charming_gates: Name or service not known

//CAT /ETC/HOSTS
    root@399c19d4adaf:/app# cat /etc/hosts
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
    172.18.0.3      399c19d4adaf
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've reviewed these, that seem to have similar issues but no definitive result.  Except one solution to specifically allocate an IP to the container, which I don't like the idea of.

[How to get Docker containers to talk to each other while running on my local host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093812/how-to-get-docker-containers-to-talk-to-each-other-while-running-on-my-local-hos)

[Can't access Docker container by name in same network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55985618/cant-access-docker-container-by-name-in-same-network)

[How to configure containers in one network to connect to each other (server -> mysql)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58931116/how-to-configure-containers-in-one-network-to-connect-to-each-other-server-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow after all that it was really simple.  I just needed to assign my own name, not accept the docker issued name.

```
//NOTE THE ADDITION OF --NAME SWITCH
PS C:\Users\johng\source\repos\Ontic5\etrade-rtd\RtdActorSystemOutOfProc> docker run --name mysqlcontainer -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase -p 3306:3306 --network testnet -d mysql:latest
0bfd4b7ff990ca2ffba8d8a200e33b7c6cee7cc422dad84f50311bfe46cdd468

//NOW CAN PING JUST FINE
PS C:\Users\johng\source\repos\Ontic5\etrade-rtd\RtdActorSystemOutOfProc> docker exec -it myexecontainer bash

root@a932138635fd:/app# ping mysqlcontainer
PING mysqlcontainer (172.18.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mysqlcontainer.testnet (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from mysqlcontainer.testnet (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
```